# Firebase getDownloadURL() and getMetadata() superfluously issue the same http request

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using the Firebase Storage Web API to display download links for a few files that I uploaded to a storage bucket.

To get the download url I'm calling `getDownloadURL()` on a reference to a [Google Cloud Storage Object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference). This gets me the url, which is fine. I make a download link out of it.

In addition to that I also call `getMetadata()` on the same reference object to get the size of the file that I want to display next to the download link. This works as well.

My issue here is that, when looking at the network traffic, I see that two identical http requests are issued. Apparently the API calls above issue the exact same http request, which seems like a waste of network resources to me.

The http response looks something like this:

```
bucket: "xxx.appspot.com"
contentDisposition: "inline; filename*=utf-8''file.zip"
contentEncoding: "identity"
contentType: "application/zip"
crc32c: "xxx"
downloadTokens: "xxx"
etag: "xxx"
generation: "123"
md5Hash: "xxx"
metageneration: "1"
name: "file.zip"
size: "71192686"
storageClass: "STANDARD"
timeCreated: "2021-01-29T11:00:34.110Z"
updated: "2021-01-29T11:00:34.110Z"
```

Like I said. I get this response for calling `getDownloadURL()` and a second time for calling `getMetadata().`

Looking at the docs I see that it was once possible to get the download url directly from the metadata. But the property [downloadURLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.FullMetadata#downloadurls) is deprecated.

My question: Is it possible to get the file url and the size of the file without issuing the same api call twice? I'm new to firebase and I can't believe that this is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct: the download URL used to be determined automatically after the fule was uploaded to Cloud Storage through a Firebase SDK.

This was changed a few years ago, to require an explicit call to generate a download URL. As far as I know there is no longer a way to get the download URL and metadata in a single API call since then.

Comment: Thank you. Not the answer I wanted to hear, but now it is confirmed at least. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Firebase, you can use the getDownloadURL() method to retrieve the download URL for a file in Cloud Storage. You can modify your code to use this method instead of the getDownloadURL() method from the previous version.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```js
import {  getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
```